# How to move numbered files into numbered folders using Python?

Tags: python, file, move, directory

I have a series of files named `mesh1`, `mesh2`, `mesh3`, and so forth. I would like to create corresponding folders, like `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3` and so on. I would also like to put the files into the folders. For example, `mesh1` should go into `folder1`, `mesh2` should go into `folder2`, etc.

Here is the code I use to create the folders:

```
for i in lst:
    os.makedirs("/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/File{}".format(i))
```

How can I move the files to the folders? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
os.rename("/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/Mesh{}.txt".format(i), "/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/File{}/Mesh{}.txt".format(i))
```

Comment: If you have two {} in your string then .format needs two arguments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
for item in items:
    os.makedirs("/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/"+str(item))
    fil="/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/"+str(item)+"/"+str(item)+".txt"
    os.rename("/home/tianxiangwang/Desktop/Simulation/"+str(item)+".txt",fil)
```